# Can I check any value in Xcode debugger?

Tags: ios, xcode

I use Xcode 6.x 
I wonder if there is a way to check(see) any variable value(including local, global) by just writing the name at any debug break point.

Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

I generally use po in Console Window or use Expression Window

```
po variablename
```

Answer (score 0):

generally use po/p for local and global variable.

Example :

1) For Array, Dictionary and String etc

po varibleName

2) For Int ,BOOL,Array's count

p variableName